# Setting dyanmic function arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the following functions in my controller that work fine with the given text:

```
  $scope.shareFbBtn=function(){

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

$cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaFacebook("Can anyone get further? #initialreaction", "http://i.imgur.com/7PkUq6f.png",null).then(function(result) {
  // Success!
  console.log("FB success");
}, function(err) {
  // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
  console.log("Facebook share did not work");
});


})
  }



 $scope.shareTwitterBtn=function(){

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
$cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaTwitter("Can anyone get further? #initialreaction", "http://i.imgur.com/7PkUq6f.png", "http://www.gogatherapp.com/press").then(function(result) {
  // Success!
  console.log(saying);
}, function(err) {
  // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
  console.log("Twitter share did not work");
});


})
  }
```

However, I would like to give the function dynamic arguments like so

```
shareFbBtn({{somethingdynamic}})
```

And replace the standard text "Can anyone get further" with the dynamic text argument.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

EDIT:
I have already tried putting the argument in the function like below but it does not work:

HTML:

```
ng-click="shareFbBtn(Hello);"
```

Controller:

```
$scope.shareFbBtn=function(text){

      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(text, "http://i.imgur.com/7PkUq6f.png",null).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
      console.log("FB success");
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
      console.log("Facebook share did not work");
    });


    })
      }
```

Comment: have you tried anything?  this is a pretty standard JavaScript problem;  accept a variable in your function declaration, and then write your variable out instead of the static text.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it does not work...but I am new to coding and may have a syntax problem...I edit my question with my attempts

Comment: `Hello` isn't a variable, you probably are meaning to pass in a string. Try `ng-click='shareFbBtn("Hello")'`

Comment: Awesome! You did it! Just a quick follow up, so if I wanted to use dynamic information would I use ng-click=shareFbBtn("{{dynamictext}}")